# FormView CRUD for a self-relationship table! Foreign key not bound in Insert/Edit methods

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, formview

I have this tables(Note `Book` table is in the self-relationship with `IdParent` as foreign key) : [image]

And I have a formView to allow CRUD operations.

Can you tell me why the IdParent remains null ? I've created a break point and I found that the IdParent is still empty (null) when I insert or edit the formView.
The I`dTypeOfBook` is bound the same way and is not null, why only the `IdParent`?

this `DropDownList` helps users to choose the parent item

```
      <td>Insert in:</td>
                    <td>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="IdParentTextBox" 
                DataSourceId="ParentBookObjectDataSource1" 
                SelectedValue='<%# CurrentBookIdHiddenField1.Value%>' 
                DataTextField="Title"  DataValueField="BookID">

            </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ParentBookObjectDataSource1" 
    runat="server" SelectMethod="ListOfAllBooks" TypeName="CodeSan.BookBusiness">

      </asp:ObjectDataSource>
     </td>
```

here is my InsertMethod `AddBook`.

```
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Insert)]
    public static void AddBook(Book book)
    {
        CodeSanEntitiesDataContext db = new CodeSanEntitiesDataContext();
        book.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        //book.IdParent = ((book.IdParent ?? 0) == 0) ? null : book.IdParent;
        db.Book.InsertOnSubmit(book);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```